# What is the algorithm of jags with discrete likelihood and continuous prior

Tags: r, jags, rjags

I am trying to understanding the following rjags code.

```
 library(rjags)

 set.seed(1)
 N <- 10
 p <- rep(10,N)


 cat("


 model {
 for (i in 1:N) {
 p[i] ~ dpois(lambda)
  }
 lambda <- 2*exp(-2*alpha*3)/(2*pow(4,2))
 alpha ~ dnorm(beta,tau)T(0,0.2)
 beta ~ dnorm(0,10000)
 tau ~ dgamma(2,0.01)
  }", file= "example1.jag")


  jags <- jags.model('example1.jag',data = list( "N" = N,"p"=p))
 update(jags, 16000)
 out_ex1<-jags.samples(jags, 'alpha',4000)
 out_ex1$alpha
```

It has poisson likelihood and normal prior, so there is no closed form for Gibbs Sampling. Then what MCMC method is used here? ARS? Slice Sampling? or Metropolis Hasting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always find out which samplers JAGS is using for stochastic variables using rjags::list.samplers - for example:

```
> list.samplers(jags)
$`base::RealSlicer`
[1] "alpha"

$`base::RealSlicer`
[1] "beta"

$`base::RealSlicer`
[1] "tau"
```

In this case this tells you that a slice sampler is being used for each of the three unobserved stochastic nodes in your model.  Slice sampling is the main workhorse in JAGS so this is quite typical, except where a more efficient (e.g. conjugate) sampler is available (or if the GLM module is loaded for an appropriate model).

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for your reply. I first tried the codes without truncation. In that case beta and tau are updated by Gibbs sampler. I am wondering why after truncation Gibbs sampler is not valid for beta and tau

Comment: Conjugates are only available in specific situations, such as a Normal likelihood and Gamma prior for tau. If you truncate the response then it is no longer a Normal likelihood so there is no valid conjugate (although you can truncate the prior and still have it as a conjugate). Similarly if you swap a Gamma for a Log Normal on tau then there is no valid conjugate, so JAGS defaults back to a slice sampler.

Comment: Hi Matt Sorry I have some extra questions to bother. Is there a way to check out each slice sampler model, like what is the posterior distribution used in the sample, and what is the adapted bandwidth of each slice sampler? Thank you.

Comment: Not as far as I’m aware. If you want that kind of detailed control you would be better with a more low-level framework.